# Bluetooth Speaker Controls Too Loud and in Too Few Steps

Tags: volume-control, bluetooth-audio, volume

I bought a set of [Dali Zensor 1 AX](https://www.dali-speakers.com/uk/loudspeakers/zensor/zensor-1-ax/) speakers which has a Bluetooth connection. Playing over the 3.5mm cable works perfectly and the volume can be nicely adjusted from the phone. The phone has 31 volume steps, with 0 being muted and 30 being 100% volume.

However, when I connect the same phone via Bluetooth, there are only 4 steps of volume control:

- 0 on phone: muted
- 1 on phone: 33% speaker volume
- 2 on phone: 66% speaker volume
- 3 on phone: 100% speaker volume

Steps 4 to 30 are all there but because the volume is already at 100% on step 3, they do nothing.

Having only 3 controls is extremely unpleasant as it's unlikely the volume I want to listen to is one of those 3 and to make matters worse, most often when I connect to the speakers it's higher than step 3 and just blasts whatever I play at 100% for a few seconds while I try to turn it down.

I've tried connecting an iPhone to it via Bluetooth and it works perfectly fine. I've also connected multiple Android phones (OnePlus 5T and OnePlus 6T) and they both show the problem.

**How can I get my Android phone to spread the Bluetooth audio volume control across all the steps rather than just the lowest 4?**

Answer (score 2):

After a couple of hours of searching I found the fix:

1. Enable `Developer options` if you haven't yet (instructions can be found online).
2. Open `Developer options`.
3. Enable the **`Disable absolute volume`** option.
4. Enjoy listening to music at whatever volume you like.

Here are the details for this option:

[image]